# Is Jesus's return on the clouds the same event as Him riding the white horse?

Tags: matthew, revelation, chronology, second-coming, olivet-discourse

Jesus says that He will return "on the clouds of the sky, with power and great glory" (Matt 24:30).

Is this the same event as when He returns on the white horse in Revelation 19?

> And I saw heaven opened, and behold a white horse; and he that sat
> upon him was called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he doth
> judge and make war (Revelation 19:11)

Or are they different events? Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi AlphaOmega, I edited the question a little bit--we try to avoid opinion-based questions to the extent possible. If you don't think my edits capture the intent of your question I can roll them back.

Comment: This is happening here because, indeed, the book of Revelation is divided into seven parts, and each part is the same subject seen from different perspectives.

Answer (score 3):

Let us compare the descriptions of the two events (with context in each case):

**Matt 24:29-31 -**

> Immediately after the tribulation of those days: ‘The sun will be
> darkened, and the moon will not give its light; the stars will fall
> from the sky, and the powers of the heavens will be shaken. At that
> time the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven,c and all the
> tribes of the earth will mourn. They will see the Son of Man coming on
> the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory.d And He will send
> out His angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather His
> elect from the four winds, from one end of the heavens to the other.

The sequence of events appears to be:

1. Tribulation
2. Sun, moon and stars darkened
3. Powers of heaven shaken
4. Sign of the Son of Man appears in heaven
5. Tribes of earth morn
6. Son of Man appears in the clouds with power and great glory (cf Rev 14:14-16)
7. Angels sent out to gather the saints with the trumpet of God (cf 1 Thess 4:16, 17)

**Rev 19:11-16 -**

> Then I saw heaven standing open, and there before me was a white
> horse. And its rider is called Faithful and True. With righteousness
> He judges and wages war. He has eyes like blazing fire, and many royal
> crowns on His head. He has a name written on Him that only He Himself
> knows. He is dressed in a robe dipped in blood,c and His name is The
> Word of God. The armies of heaven, dressed in fine linen, white and
> pure, follow Him on white horses. And from His mouth proceeds a sharp
> sword with which to strike down the nations, and He will rule them
> with an iron scepter.d He treads the winepress of the fury of the
> wrath of God the Almighty. And He has a name written on His robe and
> on His thigh: KING OF KINGS AND LORD OF LORDS.

Thus, we have the following in summary:

1. Description of Jesus (similar to Rev 1:13-16) but riding a white horse into battle
2. He is followed by the "armies of heaven" also on white horses whose riders wear "fine linen"; as per V8 this fine linen is gen by God is the the righteous acts of the saints.  That is, the armies of heaven are the saints of God
3. The weapon used to attack the enemy is the "sword from the mouth of Jesus"
4. V15 suggests that this is preparation for Jesus to rule the nations with the iron scepter (cf. Rev 11:15-18, Ps 2:9)
5. While riding the white horse, Jesus also treads the winepress of the fury of God Almighty

It is immediately obvious that this scene is highly symbolic, whereas, the scene in Matt 24:29-31 is much more literal.  The essential point is that Matt 24 is about gathering the saints at the last trumpet when the Lord returns; but by contrast, Rev 19:11-16 is about Jesus going into a spiritual war against His enemies using the armies of God.

Indeed, many commentators view Rev 19:11-16 as a description of the battle of Armageddon which is NOT described in Rev 16:16, but that is another question.  In any case, the two scenes are fundamentally different.

Comment: Dottard thank you for your answer. Much appreciated. (I'm sorry that it took almost 1 year to say thank you).

Comment: @AlphaOmega - no apology necessary (it was over two years) - glad to be of some small service.

Answer (score 0):

they are the same events. Jesus's return in the clouds is His second coming, which is for judgement. HE also will come out on a white horse but that is for His triumphal entry into the earth realm to defeat His enemies. both are the same events. I think the person above got it a bit wrong. whenever Jesus returns to the earth, He will

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. **The White Horse and the Sunrise:**

   - The description of the White Horse in Revelation implies a journey from the east to the west, from sunrise to sunset. In Revelation 19:11, the Rider is called "Faithful and True," signifying the identity of Jesus Christ.
   - The passage "He who sat on him was called Faithful and True, and in righteousness, He judges and makes war" (Revelation 19:11) resonates with Christ's mission to bring justice, peace, and subsequent judgment.
2. **Encounter with the Black Horse and the Crucifixion:**

   - The direction of the horses, as mentioned in Daniel 7:2-3, suggests a significant encounter. This meeting is interpreted as the crucifixion of Jesus, where the White Horse encounters the Black Horse.
   - The transition to the Red Horse symbolizes the transformation of Jesus' mission during the crucifixion, as foreseen in Isaiah 63:2, where His garments turn red as He treads the winepress of God's wrath.
3. **The Red Horse and Peace Taken from the Earth:**

   - The vision of the Red Horse in Revelation 6:4 is interpreted as the representation of Jesus taking peace from the earth, as stated in Matthew 10:34: "I did not come to bring peace, but a sword."
   - The large sword given to the Rider symbolizes the shift from Christ's peaceful message to one that provokes division and spiritual confrontation.
4. **The White Horse Turning Red and Divine Judgment:**

   - The change of the White Horse's color to Red is associated with Christ's judgment upon all humanity. This transformation reflects the divine judgment process described in Revelation, where Christ exercises His sovereign authority over the nations (Daniel 7:9-10).
   - Christ's judgment upon all is highlighted as a crucial element of the narrative, connecting the symbolic events of the horses to the divine responsibility of judging every individual.
5. **The Pale Horse and the Great Tribulation:**

   - The connection between the Pale Horse of Revelation and the Dappled Grey Horse (yellowish-green) of Daniel 7:4 indicates the onset of the great tribulation.
   - The yellow color, associated with the decomposition of a corpse, suggests a period of intense affliction and judgment, aligning with the vision of the great tribulation in Revelation.